# Rename columns in table mysql

Tags: mysql, alter-table

Is it possible to rename more than one column in mysql database once?
For example I have table Person with columns Name, Surname, Age... and I want to rename them to Person%Name, Person%Surname, Person%Age automatically.

Comment: I don't think percent sign is allowed for columns name

Comment: it was only bad example....

Comment: What do you mean by 'automatically'? I think you probably want `ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE COLUMN ``Name`` ``NewName`` VARCHAR(100),...` see [MySQL doc on `ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html) - note that those should be single back-ticks, but I am not sure what the escape is for the backtick literal within code for comments.

Comment: i mean not to rename only one column at once but to rename all columns of table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Syntax :**

```
   ALTER TABLE "table_name"
    Change "column 1" "column 1" ["Data Type"],
    Change "column 2" "column 2" ["Data Type"],
    Change "column 3" "column 3" ["Data Type"],
    ........
```

**Example :**

ALTER TABLE MEMBERS 
   CHANGE name First Name CHAR(100), 
   Surname new_Surname INT;